# server to server upload

Tags: server, upload

I know nothing about coding, API's, etc I just have a very simple question:

When I want to upload to website, e.g. youtube, soundcloud, etc WHY is it not possible to point to a file on a server, rather than one on my local computer?

I've tried setting up onedrive as a network drive in windows 10 and I can point to files there, but all that happens is the file is transferred THROUGH my computer and uploaded back up.

Is there an easy solution to this problem?

Comment: thanks... I think there's some of your comment missing?

Comment: Redo:
In the example that you gave, your computer has obtained authentication into the OneDrive network drive. OneDrive then authorizes a session with your computer and network address to let a download happen. Similarly, when you upload to YouTube, it authenticates your computer and address to allow it. However, if you simply try to connect OneDrive directly to YouTube, it would not recognized the authentication as belonging to you (different address) A work around is to map OneDrive locally. If you do this, Windows 10 should work as if it's local will upload.

Comment: I tried that as well, have had both Onedrive and Google drive mapped locally with a drive letter assigned. Still the upload happens through my connection.

Comment: When you map a network drive your operating system (OS) "pretends" that the drive is local. When you upload a file through that same OS, it will handle the upload through a TCP connection to the destination. I believe you are asking: "why cannot the network drive connect directly to the upload destination without going through the OS?" In theory, this is possible, but it would require more functionality than what comes out of the box. Your OS would need to provide the network drive with the destination's authentication info. This is very complicated and risky. But it must exist somewhere...